# Locate ErrorProvider on Windows Form at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making an extension method library to use in windows form applications. One of the methods I intend to create will make setting error states on input controls easier, e.g.

```
public static void SetError(this System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox, string errorMessage)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
    {
        //reset control state
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
    }
    else
    {
        //set background colour to a nice shade of red
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose;
    }

    //try to locate an ErrorProvider on the control's containing form.
    var errorProvider = LocateErrorProvider(textBox);

    if (errorProvider != null)
    {
        //set error message on error provider (or clear it)
        errorProvider.SetError(textBox, errorMessage);
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out the `LocateErrorProvider` method. What I would like to do is check whether an ErrorProvider exists on my form and then only make use of it if it does exist.

ErrorProvider is a `Component` and not a `Control`, so I can't get to it via the `form.Controls` property. I have tried casting the parent form into a variety of objects, to no avail.

**UPDATE**: I have managed to get to the ErrorProvider using reflection using the following code:

```
private static System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider GetErrorProvider(System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
{
    //get the containing form of the control
    var form = control.GetContainerControl();

    //use reflection to get to "components" field
    var componentField = form.GetType().GetField("components", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (componentField != null)
    {
        //get the component collection from field
        var components = componentField.GetValue(form);

        //locate the ErrorProvider within the collection
        return (components as System.ComponentModel.IContainer).Components.OfType<System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Personally, I'm not too fond of using the hard-coded field name to get to the field. But in this case it seems to work just fine. Does anybody have a better way to achieve the same results?

Comment: There's a `components` collection that is used in the default implementation of the `Dispose` method. I don't recall if it's `private` or `protected`, but that shouldn't matter since you're accessing it from an object of the same class.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Thanks, I've tried getting to that field, but it's proving to be a challenge. It's not a collection that's implicitly tied to a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, but rather a design-time variable added by Visual Studio to the Form class. I've tried using reflection to get to that field, and I've managed to "glimpse" the ErrorProvider, but I have not yet been able to really "get" to it.

Comment: I have managed to get to the error provider using reflection. If anybody has an alternate way, please post your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, this seems to solve my problem:

```
private static System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider GetErrorProvider(System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
{
    //get the containing form of the control
    var form = control.GetContainerControl();

    //use reflection to get to "components" field
    var componentField = form.GetType().GetField("components", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (componentField != null)
    {
        //get the component collection from field
        var components = componentField.GetValue(form);

        //locate the ErrorProvider within the collection
        return (components as System.ComponentModel.IContainer).Components.OfType<System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Hans & Cody for their excellent ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is what interfaces are designed to do.  They enforce a class to implement behavior.  The behavior you want here is for a form to have an ErrorProvider.  So write an interface like this:

```
public interface IHasErrorProvider {
    ErrorProvider Provider { get; }
}
```

And have the forms with an error provider implement the interface:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IHasErrorProvider {
    public ErrorProvider Provider {
        get { return errorProvider1; }
    }
    // etc..
}
```

Retrieving the error provider is now simple:

```
    private static ErrorProvider GetErrorProvider(Control control) {
        var impl = control.FindForm() as IHasErrorProvider;
        return impl != null ? impl.Provider : null;
    }
```

Comment: I like this idea, the only problem is that I cannot always control the form itself. Thanks, though!

Comment: If you can't control the form then you can't control it having an ErrorProvider either.  The outcome is the exact same, you'll get a null.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I'm only using the errorprovider if it's there, but I don't want the user to have to change anything on the form; my method needs to figure it out for itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in VS2005 this works:

```
    private static System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider GetErrorProvider(System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
    {
        try
        {
            //get the containing form of the control
            System.Windows.Forms.IContainerControl form = control.GetContainerControl();

            //use reflection to get to "components" field
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo componentField = form.GetType().GetField("components", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            if (componentField != null)
            {
                //get the component collection from field
                object components = componentField.GetValue(form);
                object oReturn = null;
                //locate the ErrorProvider within the collection
                foreach (object o in ((System.ComponentModel.Container)components).Components)
                {
                    if (o.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider))
                    {
                        oReturn = o;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return (ErrorProvider)oReturn;
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```