# Method to return extending type instance from extended control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my solution, I have a custom component which implements `IExtenderProvider` in order to provide properties to other controls. I would like to implement a method for that component which, taking a control as argument, would return the instance of the extender component it is associated with, something like this:

```
    Public Function GetErrorProvider(c As Control) As MyErrorProvider
        Dim errorProvider as MyErrorProvider
        'Some code here
        Return errorProvider 
    End Function
```

I thought of simply looking at the form and looping for a control of the `MyErrorProvider` type and use that, as I am not going to have more than one of this component per form, but I would like a more direct approach. I want this for some logic that depends on runtime defined values for that instance, outside the scope of forms.

Any ideas/suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I may need more on what you're trying to do.  The only way I can think of doing this is by checking the container(form) for the error provider in a way you're already describing.  `For Each mEP in  FormContainingErrorProvider.Controls.OfType(Of MyErrorProvider)()
Next`  You can then pass the control's handle back to the caller?

Comment: @JimmySmith The problem is way more complex than I thought. Your solution doesn't work because it doesn't return **components**. Apparently, the only way to get a component from a form is by using reflection, in a really non-intuitive way.

Comment: Derp, this makes sense as I was looking at it as a control.  This looks hairy, but you might [be able to work with it](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?621192-Get-a-list-of-Components-on-a-Form)

Comment: @JimmySmith It looks like I've managed to pull it off by converting the code from the solution here to VB.NET (automatic converter):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817359/locate-errorprovider-on-windows-form-at-run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness purposes, I am adding the solution that worked converted from the C# code linked above and adjusted slightly. It appears this can only be accomplished with reflection (correct me if I am wrong!):

```vbs
Public Shared Function GetErrorProvider(control As Control) As MyErrorProvider
    'get the containing form of the control
    Dim form = control.GetContainerControl()

    'use reflection to get to "components" field
    Dim componentField = form.[GetType]().GetField("components", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)

    If componentField IsNot Nothing Then
        'get the component collection from field
        Dim components = componentField.GetValue(form)

        'locate the ErrorProvider within the collection
        Return TryCast(components, IContainer).Components.OfType(Of MyErrorProvider)().FirstOrDefault()
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```